# The minimum element in a numpy array remaining zero even after adding one to every element pointwise

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the log of an image for some further processing, the minimum pixel value in the image is zero and hence i am trying to take log(1+image), but even after adding 1 to every element the minimum value of the array is still showing as 0 and hence *np.log* is throwing a *divide by zero encountered in log* and setting the value to *-inf* which is causing me problems down the line.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.io as io

image = io.imread('./PET_image.tif')
image_2 = image + 1
print(np.amin(image))
print(np.amin(image_2))
np.log(image)
```

both the print *np.amin()* statements are printing out 0.

```
0
0
error.py:8: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  np.log(image_2)
```

But after adding 1 to the array shouldn't the minimum value be 1? I'm pretty sure I'm missing something extremely stupid, but this is making my head split and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding 1 to the image and then applying `log`. You can just do

```
np.log1p(image)
```

which is essentially doing the same thing that you are trying to achieve with that `+1`.

The error that you are facing with the `+1` is caused by the type of the array `dtype=uint8`. Adding 1 to all the pixels will turn the pixels that have value 255 to 0.

Or you can add the 1 only to pixels where the value is 0.

```
image[np.where(image == 0)] = 1
```

Comment: Oh now i get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely due to `image.dtype` being unsigned (e.g. `uint8`), which makes sense since the pixel values are always positive. Due to the data type, pixels with value 255 will overflow when you add one and change to zero.

```
image = io.imread('./PET_image.tif').astype(np.uint64)
```

to read into an array of 64-bit integers which won't overflow (so easily).

Comment: Oh hey, this worked. Thanks. But I didn't quite get what the problem is though? even if it is uint8 it should still be able to hold all values from 0-255 right? and when adding 1 all the zero values should become 1 leaving the minimum as 1? Could you elaborate a little?

Edit: The answer by @MatusDubrava cleared my doubt. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oops, I got a bit confused there. It's actually an overflow issue. I edited the answer.